# Trouble with calculation in a pivot table

Tags: python, aggregate

I have the following table

[image: Example]

Where I want

- Initial = depo from the day before
- Final = Initial + IN - OUT

My questions:

1. How to make the table which contains the calculation from above?
2. How do I do the calculation which is aggregated from the previous row?
3. If I write a function using shift(1) which takes the value from previous cell, how do I make it stop calculating when A is finished?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you edit your post to include the code you've written so far?

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I haven’t written any code yet as regards to this problem. This table had multiple entries for each day, so what I did was group by the date and in and ticker, and pivoted the table. The above is an example I drew from that df. I don’t know how to take the value from In and Out to calculate Final, and bring that Final to Initial to calculate another Final for the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working off the dataframe structure that you provided above, here's one way to do it without using shifts.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('my_sample_data.xls', header=[0,1])
>>>df
              Ticker               Date Quantity       Price       Quantity_depo       Price_depo
  Unnamed: 0_level_1 Unnamed: 1_level_1       In   Out    In   Out       Initial Final    Initial Final
0                  A         2001-01-01        0  1000     0  9595           NaN   NaN        NaN   NaN
1                  A         2001-01-02       25   620    25   516           NaN   NaN        NaN   NaN
2                  A         2001-01-03      655  2660   655  2660           NaN   NaN        NaN   NaN
3                  A         2001-01-04        3   555   894   555           NaN   NaN        NaN   NaN
4                  B         2001-01-01        0  1000     0  9595           NaN   NaN        NaN   NaN
5                  B         2001-01-02       25   620    25   516           NaN   NaN        NaN   NaN
6                  B         2001-01-03      655  2660   655  2660           NaN   NaN        NaN   NaN
7                  B         2001-01-04        3   555   894   555           NaN   NaN        NaN   NaN

# Count of rows for each ticker
tkr = df.loc[:,'Ticker']
tkr.columns = ['Ticker']
gp = tkr.groupby('Ticker')['Ticker'].count()
gp_dict = {k:v for k,v in zip(gp.index, gp)}

idx = 0
for v in gp_dict.values():
    # Compute for the first row
    df.loc[idx, ('Quantity_depo', 'Initial')] = 10000 # Example
    df.loc[idx, ('Quantity_depo', 'Final')] = df.loc[idx, ('Quantity_depo', 'Initial')] + df.loc[idx, ('Quantity', 'In')] - df.loc[idx, ('Quantity', 'Out')]
    v += idx

    # Now fill up the rest of the rows
    for ix, value in df.loc[idx+1:v-1].iterrows():
        df.loc[ix, ('Quantity_depo', 'Initial')] = df.loc[ix-1, ('Quantity_depo', 'Final')]
        df.loc[ix, ('Quantity_depo', 'Final')] = df.loc[ix, ('Quantity_depo', 'Initial')] + df.loc[ix, ('Quantity', 'In')] - df.loc[ix, ('Quantity', 'Out')]

    # For the next loop
    idx += v

>>>df
             Ticker               Date Quantity       Price       Quantity_depo         Price_depo
  Unnamed: 0_level_1 Unnamed: 1_level_1       In   Out    In   Out       Initial   Final    Initial Final
0                  A         2001-01-01        0  1000     0  9595       10000.0  9000.0        NaN   NaN
1                  A         2001-01-02       25   620    25   516        9000.0  8405.0        NaN   NaN
2                  A         2001-01-03      655  2660   655  2660        8405.0  6400.0        NaN   NaN
3                  A         2001-01-04        3   555   894   555        6400.0  5848.0        NaN   NaN
4                  B         2001-01-01        0  1000     0  9595       10000.0  9000.0        NaN   NaN
5                  B         2001-01-02       25   620    25   516        9000.0  8405.0        NaN   NaN
6                  B         2001-01-03      655  2660   655  2660        8405.0  6400.0        NaN   NaN
7                  B         2001-01-04        3   555   894   555        6400.0  5848.0        NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how to stop it from iterating when A is finished and start over again from B?

Comment: @StevenWong I see what you mean now. I do not have a one-line solution, unfortunately. What I can think of is, provided that your df is sorted by Ticker, you can then get a count of rows for each Ticker i.e. `df.groupby('Ticker').count()`. Thereafter, you can loop through them with the set of operations above.

Comment: @StevenWong I've updated my answer but unfortunately I am unable to test it properly now. However, I think it should give you an idea on the method that I'm trying to use in my answer

Comment: Yeah it was a headache to me. What I did was to separate the ticker to different de and apply the formula. Thank you for helping!